# Missing content field types in orchard core

Tags: asp.net-core, orchardcore

I'm new to Orchard Core. Some of the content field types are missing in my saas-ed recipe site, but I can see it in blog recipe. I only see 4 types such as Geo Point Field, Markdown Field, Media Field and Taxonomy Field. But I cannot see Boolean field etc. Did I messed up something? How do I re-enable those types again?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable those in the **Features** section [in the Features menu in Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqDda.png). Select the required **Features** like say HTML, Liquid, etc. as you wanted and click on **Enable** button individually to enable the relevant **Features** in your running Orchard instance.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34033291)